# Datastore key get() method returns None

Tags: google-app-engine, key, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Here I create an NDB key and load the entity with the .get() method.

```
GlobalMessagesKey = ndb.Key('TCADBsystem','TCADB','MessageList','Global') 
GlobalMessage = GlobalMessagesKey.get()
```

This returns None. This worked before. Nothing happens with they key in between creating and using the get method ( as you can see in the code ).

What have I done wrong? The key is formatted exactly as the documentation describes it should be.

The entity I reference to with this key is in the datastore with that exact ID and parent. There are no typos and the class used in the key is the same as that of the entity.

Comment: Did you actually save the entity in the DB? (I don't see a `.put()` call)

Comment: Yes, I said the entity is in the datastore.

Comment: Ugh, right :) Print the key you get and compare it with the one you see in the datastore browser for that entity. Do they match?

Comment: Do you mean to print with .urlsafe()? If I print the key, I just get what I formatted like above, with .urlsafe() I get a key which only matches partially with the key I see in the datastore. ( Which looks like this : ahdkZXZ-dGhuZHJjbG91ZC0zLXNlY3VyZXIXCxILTWVzc2FnZUxpc3QiBkdsb2JhbAw )

Comment: A partial match suggests you're missing something in the ancestry path, which would be a reason for the None result of `.get()`.

Comment: 'TCADB' in my code posted here is the only parent and root entity of this entity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100243/discussion-between-dan-cornilescu-and-icipiracy).

Answer (score 1):

My entity class used a property named 'parent'. This was a mistake because the 'parent' property is reserved for the datastore. This broke the datastore.

I renamed this property to something else ( not 'parent' ) and it fixed my problem.